# Lua io.popen() - Accessing Shared Drive on Windows

Tags: windows, lua, popen

I am running a Lua program on a Windows 10 machine.  This Windows 10 computer is networked to another Windows 10 computer and this other computer is sharing its D: drive with my computer.  The shared drive is called the O: drive by my computer.

When I open a cmd window on my computer and type:

`type "O:\Data\config\file.xml"`

I get the contents of file.xml in my cmd window.  However, if I run this same command through Lua:

`f = io.popen([["type O:\Data\config\file.xml"]])`

`output = f:read("*l")`

Then `output` returns as `nil`.

This behavior is true of any command involving the shared O: drive, not just `type`.  Similarly, I have some bat scripts that reference the O: drive, and I call these using `os.execute`, but they are not able to accomplish their task (I can see they are actually executing, just not correctly).  However, if I run similar commands or scripts with the local D: or C: drives, I do not have this issue.

Any ideas as to what could be different between these two calls?  Is there a different way I can call the O: drive?

Comment: `output = f:read("*1")`  The `*1` is invalid format.

Comment: What is the result of `io.popen[[net use O:]]:read"a"` ?

Comment: ```io.popen([[net use O:]]):read("*a")``` returns a blank output.  I also tried ```net use \\IAS\o\``` since this is the remote name of the drive, and this also returned a blank output.  If I just ```read("*l")``` on either of those I get ```nil```

Comment: Is there any way to get command error from popen so I can maybe see why it's not returning?

Comment: I was thinking `out, err = io.popen( cmd )` but nada...  Might have to pipe stderr to temp.txt, then read it from there.  `out = io.popen( cmd 2> temp.txt )`

Comment: `Is there any way to get command error` - Yes, if you're using LuaJIT.  You can use FFI to invoke `GetLastError` WinAPI function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Lua application was running as a service, and I determined that when it was running as a service it was running as a 'guest' user, rather than my system user.  Therefore, it did not have the appropriate permissions to run.

I modified my Windows service to run as my specific user, and this resolved the issue.